# how to receive a response of a document.createElement('form') javascript

Tags: javascript, post

I have a post request

```
        let f = document.createElement('form');
        f.setAttribute('method', 'post');
        f.setAttribute('action', paymentResponse.acsUrl);

        //create hidden input elements
        config.keys.forEach((item: { name: string; value: string }) => {
          let i = document.createElement('input');
          i.type = 'hidden';
          i.name = item.name;
          i.value = item.value;
          f.appendChild(i); //Add it to the form
        });

        document.body.appendChild(f); //Add the form to the body
        f.submit(); //Submit it immediately
```

Now I want to the response of this post request.

How to get the response?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add an event listener to the form. Something like this:

```
f.addEventListener('submit', onSubmit);

async function onSubmit(ev) {
 ev.preventDefault();
 const form = new FormData(ev.target);
 const item = form.get('item'); //get the items you want to submit

const response = await fetch(url, {
method: 'Post',
headers: {
           Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
body: JSON.stringify(data) // the data is an object from the items from the form
});

const result = await response.json();
}
```

The result is the response of your post request. May be you should put the fetch in a try-catch block for errors. Note that may be you should create a button or anchor with type="submit" and append it to the form.